# Translation of a exhortatory phrase of encouragement to remain cheerful in difficult circumstances

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

The trans phrase I am looking for a colloquial translation of is ‘keep your chin up!’I received a birthday card from an in-law with the phrase sursum mentum—-I have been waiting a long time for a knee operation—-which is clearly wrong and anyway far too literal, despite the Western liturgical Latin ‘sursum corda!’I thought of something like ‘persevera! or, better, erecto animo esto! but I’m sure that Plautus or Terence, perhaps also Petronius, might have some phrases more colloquial. Perhaps the Terentine bono animo fac sis is a good starting point.

Comment: I merged the other question's edits into this one, since this is the one with upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I wanted to delete the shorter version of the question but was unable.

Answer (score 1):

Salvē Iōhannē! Id quod quaeris nōn dissimile esse vidētur huic quaestiōnī: ["Look at the bright side" in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16814). Namque ego ad eam respondēns plūrīs locūtiōnēs prōposuī quibus animī cūra et sollicitūdō allevārētur, sed in tuā rē nihil eōrum ita convenīre putō ut convenit illud ***bonō animō es**(tō); fac sīs* illud quod memorās cum familiārius dictum sit, tum magis est superiōris ad īnferiōrem loquentis. Praetereā invēnī ***habē animum bonum.*** Haec igitur imprīmīs suāserim; sīn autem magis variātās requīris, ēn aliquot:

- *[ades animō](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/43/7/4233-4237#7) et omitte timōrem/cūram/sollicitūdinem!* – ā Mārcō Tulliō probātum.
- *[cōnfirmā animum](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=animum%20%7E%20confirm)!* – hoc saepe dīcitur in rē dubiā, quasi dīcās 'pertināx es et prōpositum sequere', vērum hilaritātem nōn admodum refert.
- *[ērige animum (dēmissum)](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/10/11/1675-1679#11)!* mihi nescioquid bellicōsum sonat; *ērēctō animō estō* aut stoicum aut tragicum.
- hoc tamen *[ērige tē](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23erige+te), Lūcilī virōrum optime; ērige tē et cōnfirmā!* jam multō aptius, paene 'dēsinās ineptīre'.

  - [hōc locō](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/7/6/364-382#6) cōpulantur 'laetī atque ērēctī' oppōnunturque eō 'animō dēmissō atque humilī'; aliīs locīs jungitur 'laetus' cum 'alacrī, bene valentī' etc., vērum in imperandī modō *laetus es(tō)* nūsquam reperiō.
- [***nē jacē**/nē jaceās*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/57/301/849-859#301) – hīc ipsam adhortātiōnem nōn vidēmus, sed eandem ā Cicerōne tamquam redditam audīmus: *nē jacē! # (egone) nē jaceam?* Modus imperātīvus hōc locō mihi magis placet quia et īnstantior est et, crēdō, cotīdiānī sermōnis proprius. Adde quod idem 'jacēre' et eō oppōnitur quod est 'vigēre'.
- Vērum enim vērō suspicor ego Rōmānōs, sī quid 'bonō animō' ēlegantius quaererent, nihil prōmptius dictūrōs quam ***[χαῖρε](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%AF%CF%81%CF%89).***

Cēterum nōnnūlla hōrum quandoquidem simul ad animum et ad corpus spectant necnōn ad crūra, lūsum verbōrum efficere possunt ut nōn omnīnō cōmem ita satis facētum... :-)