# Can someone translate “trust all is well" or "all is well” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This is for a tattoo so the most accurate translation is much appreciated :)

I thought the translation would be:
Trust all is well: Confido omnia bene
All is well: Omnis bene est

Comment: I'm not sure what "trust all is well or all is well" might mean in English. Can you explain this sentence.

Comment: Oh I was saying translate both. They are separate. So what is the English translation for “trust all is well” and “all is well”. My apologies I can see how that can be confusing.

Comment: user 13731: Take a look at this answer from cnread: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4449/1982.